# How to block only redirects via HTML meta tag with CSP

Tags: http-headers, xss, content-security-policy, meta-tags, websecurity

#### Scenario

Given there's the following HTML markup, which is the result of a successfully XSS injection attempt:

```html
<!-- this meta tag was successfully injected/prepended -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=https://evil.anyhost.it/">

<!-- original markup of the site -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>...</title>
    <script src="/assets/app.js" type="module"></script>
  </head>
  <body>...</body>
</html>
```

Using the following Content-Security-Policy would block the `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` redirection, but would also deny loading any valid scripts like `/assets/app.js`.

```
Content-Security-Policy:
  default-src 'self';
  object-src 'none';
  base-uri 'none';
  sandbox;
```

When the CSP declaration `sandbox allow-scripts allow-same-origin` is used, the script at `/assets/app.js` can be loaded and executed, but it also allows the redirection again.

#### Question

Which Content-Security-Policy would block the HTTP redirection (initiated by the injected `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` payload), but would still allow valid same-origin scripts? Thx!